# Hyphenating Compound Nouns

Tags: hyphenation, compound-words, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/) says hyphenating is necessary for a compound adjective before a noun as follows.

- The municipal government is funding a **community-based** education system.
- **Wind-powered** generators can be excellent sources of electricity.
- Many veterinarians find **meat-fed** cats to be quite healthy.

But when is hyphenating necessary for a compound noun? [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/) recommends checking a dictionary.

- [**Mother-in-law**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mother-in-law)
- **Master-at-arms**
- **Editor-in-chief** or [**editor-at-large**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/editor-at-large)

Are there detailed guidelines if dictionaries say nothing? For example,

- Wikipedia: A [**flight-to-liquidity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight-to-liquidity) is a financial market phenomenon occurring when investors sell what they perceive to be less liquid or higher risk investments, and purchase more liquid investments instead, such as US Treasuries.
- Barron's: Even gold is getting hit in the [**flight to liquidity**](https://www.barrons.com/articles/richard-bransons-virgin-orbit-seeks-1-billion-valuation-in-fundraising-51602443032), losing $13 to $1215.
- Bloomberg: In addition, there were few signs of a [**flight to liquidity**](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-06-12/jpmorgan-says-bitcoin-crash-survival-shows-it-has-staying-power) within the asset class.
- MarketWatch: Gold prices on Wednesday dropped back to their lowest settlement since December, signaling a [**flight to liquidity**](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/gold-edges-lower-as-stock-market-plunge-points-to-further-deleveraging-2020-03-18) by investors will continue to outweigh the metal’s traditional haven appeal as equities see another round of heavy losses on worries over the economic impact of the COVID-19 pandemic.

Are the hyphens in the first Wikipedia example necessary?

Comment: This is English.  There are no *rules*, only *guidelines*.

Comment: When discussing orthography on the web, including grammarly and wikipedia, what you get is opinions. Since all English [punctuation]() is largely a matter of opinion, your opinion is as good as theirs, provided you state it with complete authority.

Comment: I ask myself if the hyphenated version gives me something I wouldn't have otherwise. If a  big-time scale is different from a big time scale, then I use the version I need. If they are not different, I skip the hyphens.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments—I changed rules to guidelines but still wonder if there are patterns or tendencies for hyphenated compound nouns. I think "He recovered," and "He re-covered," are clearly different but, as a non-native user, wonder if "parents in law" and "parents-in-law" are that much different.

Comment: I support use of hyphens in phrases like community-based, wind-powered, etc.